# Python, store the number of training and validation images obtained from ImageDataGenerator in variables for use later on

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following python code which I run in Google Colab Notebooks which uses ImageDataGenerator to split out a development set into training and validation.

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    validation_split=0.35)

train_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    subset='training' 
    )

val_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    base_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    subset='validation')
```

The output of the code is below:

```
Found 4708 images belonging to 40 classes.
Found 2512 images belonging to 40 classes.
```

I want to store the values (4708 and 2512) in variables (eg train_size and val_size) for use later on. Please can someone explain how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve those numbers as a result from `flow_from_directory()`.

What you can do instead (since I presume you want to feed `steps_per_epoch = training_set_length // batch_size` and the same for `validation_steps`), you can write some arbitrary Python code to solve this problem.

For example, you could get the number by:

```
class_subfolders = [os.path.join(main_folder,class_subfolder) for class_subfolder in os.scandir(main_folder)]
#Either training or validation, depending on what 'main_folder' you feed
number_of_samples = sum([len(os.listdir(class_subfolder)) for class_subfolder in class_subfolders]
```

Comment: You are welcome. Since you accepted this answer as the solving one, could you please also upvote the answer besides the acceptance. Thank you